# HADR_LOGPROGRESS_SYNC Wait Type on SELECT Queries

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

Very recently we started to notice a new wait type (HADR_LOGPROGRESS_SYNC) pop up in our environment and cause very brief (< 60 seconds) "outages"/issues noticeable to users.

Here is what we have so far:

- The server this occurs on is large (96 core, 1.5tb RAM, 3tb tempdb,
  10-14k batch/requests/sec) and is running enterprise sql 2017
- This server contains both writes (e.g. OLTP/Redo Thread/ETLs) as well as read only RCSI workloads.
- The queries suffering the most (by far) from this wait type are all **SELECT** sprocs (no wrapping of transactions or anything involving DUI operations that we can find)
- The SELECT sprocs mentioned above are highly optimized (milliseconds exec time) and fire off frequently (e.g. one of the sprocs fires off 150k times in 10 minute span)
- 2 weeks ago we enabled trace flag 12310 to mitigate HADR_SYNC_COMMIT issues due to what we believe was AG flood gate throttling, since enabling our HADR_SYNC_COMMIT wait types have subsided. Could this additional throughput have caused contention with the LOGPROGRESS lock that has to occur back on the primary essentially moving the issue?
- The issue has occurred 3 times in the last week, all around the top of the hour 3 minutes after (e.g. 12:03pm, 3:03pm, 4:03pm) indicating a job or ETL that is likely kicking off, but we have not found anything just yet

The only blog we have found regarding this wait type is this one: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/lesson-learned-from-an-availability-group-performance-case/ba-p/319159

The blog does an excellent job explaining the wait type, but the issue in regards to what we are seeing makes no sense. First of all, the main queries experiencing the symptoms have no type of DUI operations within them. Second, those same queries are running against a read only replica so I would expect to see this potentially on a primary. Yes, their are primary databases on this server as mentioned previously, but the symptom queries have nothing to do with those databases.

From reading the blog post and trying to match it up with what we are seeing, the only thing I can think of is that the read queries in question run so frequently that they are jumping on the schedulers and somehow that becomes intertwined with the system thread that is acquiring the LOGPROGRESS lock and thus seeing a wait type that does not actually apply to them. This is a bold statement, which is more than likely not correct.

Example of a spike:
[image]

[image]

Edit: A few minutes after I made this post, I was watching closely at our servers and sure enough the issue occurred around 12:03 ET again. I was running whoisactive on several servers and I noticed quite a few MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT and PFS PAGELATCH waits. Their were also some SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD sprinkled in, but it wasn't anything super concerning or out of the ordinary.

Comment: It seems as though following the blog post in terms of troubleshooting methodology should get you the data needed to RCA your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the blog does not discuss tempdb nor SELECT queries, which I believe may be contributing to the issue. I do believe that non-yielding schedulers (to some degree) are a part of the problem, but the link to troubleshoot appears to be broken. We opened a ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: That's because that blog takes a logical approach to the issue and lets the data show where to go, which is exactly how it should be approached here.